# Use a Form response to create a folder in Drive when form is submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a Google form, first question is "Client Name" I would like my script to create a folder in Drive and have the name of the folder be the response to the "Client Name" question.

```
 function main() { 

var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) 
  var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
 }
     DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(itemResponse);

}
```

I've been trying different combinations of this but have had no success.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a on form submit event. Assuming that the Client Name is the first question, then the following on form submit installable trigger added to the form will create the folder with the given name:

```
function createFolder(e) {
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses()
  var name = items[0].getResponse();
  DriveApp.createFolder(name);
}
```

Related

- [How to get form values in the submit event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43429161/1595451)