# How to append Google Form responses to Google sheets using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Google sheet that can read and store information from a Google form. I need this program to take the fields when the form submits and append them to my Google sheet. The code below automatically creates a sheet that holds the information from the form.

I am currently using logger to see if they are getting any of the 
information from the form. They are not.

How can I retrieve each value from the form and then programatically append it to a sheet I created?

```
function formSubmit(e)
{

  // Function level variables
  var date = e.values[0];
  var name = e.values[1];
  var phone = e.values[2];

  // Get the spread sheet that contains the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FpRbYC-
  nfltxoalGV974aDX6A_fEy_MBYBShruRRYfM');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetId(0);

  if(sheet)
  {
    Logger.log(name);
  }
  else
  {
  Logger.log(phone)
  }


  // Add submission to DB
  sheet.appendRow([date,name,phone]);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this answer?

### Modification and confirmation points :

1. An error occurs at `var sheet = ss.getSheetId(0);`. When the form is submitted, script below `if (sheet) {` is not run because of the error. The detail information of `getSheetId()` is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetId()). If you want to import data to 1st page in Spreadsheet, please use `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];`.
2. Please confirm whether `formSubmit(e)` which is your function is [installed as a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) as `From Spreadsheet` and `On form submit`. By installing a trigger, you can retrieve the submitted values by your script. You can see the detail information at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429161/how-to-get-form-values-in-the-submit-event-handler/43433069#43433069).

### Modified script :

In your case, if you want to retrieve the values of the check-boxs using `e.values`, when the question in only one, you can do it using `e.values[1].split(", ")`. When there are several questions, you can retrieve each value using `e.namedValues["### question name ###"]`.

From your script, here, it supposes the former.

```
function formSubmit(e) {
  var values = e.values[1].split(", ");
  var date = values[0];
  var name = values[1];
  var phone = values[2];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FpRbYC-nfltxoalGV974aDX6A_fEy_MBYBShruRRYfM');
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  if (sheet) {
    Logger.log(name);
  } else {
    Logger.log(phone);
  }
  sheet.appendRow([date,name,phone]);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Is your event trigger from the form or from the spreadsheet.  If it's from the spreadsheet then these are the parameters passed by the event object: authmode, values, range and namedValues.  If it's from the form then these are the parameters: authmode, response and source.