# Google Form onsubmit getting user email and full name

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms, email-address

We have requirement that a email response will be sent to who fills in the form with email address and user name. All users are within single organization and have signed in Google account.

How Onsubmit function gets email address and user name ?

Comment: You may check the [`getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getEmail()) method which gets the user's email address, if available. If security policies do not allow access to the user's email address, this method returns a blank string. You may also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43433069/5832311) for additional information.

Comment: See [Quickstart: Add-on for Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms-add-on)