# How to read Google Form Data Using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm new to App Script. I'm trying to read the submitted data using App Script. I tried to use the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429161/how-to-get-form-values-in-the-submit-event-handler/43433069), but I'm not able to read it.

I tried many other method, they are also not working.

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1_HABIBYRZ-zsEMuzMCnsrAOYFlQSKwaIhmeT1y2SY6Y');
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  MailApp.sendEmail ("test@appirio.com", "Form Submited: Foo feedback " + Date.now(), +formResponses);
}
```

I also want to know, how to debug any issue in App Script.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. You need to qualify the details of what works and what does not. How does the output deviate from your expectation? Are there errors? Etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Questions on this site should be specific, make a post for each question. Anyway the built-in debugging tools are on described https://developers.google.com/apps-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer above may work, but it's a bit complicated. To let you keep the form responses as a variable inside your program, which would allow you to email it, you can do this:

```
 function formResponsesToArray() {
  var app = FormApp.openById(...),
  responses = app.getResponses(), stringResponses = []

  responses.forEach(function(r) {
    var response = []
    r.getItemResponses().forEach(function(i) {
      response.push(i.getResponse())
    })

    stringResponses.push(response)
  })

  Logger.log(stringResponses)
}
```

Which will log an array of responses like this:

[image: logger window of responses]

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd recommend doing it is feed your form responses into a google sheet, and then export is as a csv via attachment in an email. like so below. It is important to make sure the correct API's are active, such as Drive API, Gmail API and that your oauthScopes are added to the manifest if need be.

---

editing my answer to recommend stewarts answer. much cleaner, simpler and way more efficient.

```
function ExportToCSVCrntMonth(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //change this to sheet name
 // Change the below line to get the folder where you want the CSV files stored.
 var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(ss.getName().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_') + '_csv_' + new Date().getTime());
 fileName = ss.getName() + ".csv";
 var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFileCrnt_(fileName, ss);
 folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);

 var csvmail = folder.getFilesByName('your sheet name + .csv');
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "your email ere",
  subject: "CSV attached",
  body: "body text",

  attachments: [csvmail.next()]
  });
 }

function convertRangeToCsvFileCrnt_(csvFileName, ss) {
var activeRange = ss.getDataRange();
 try {
   var data = activeRange.getValues();
   var csvFile = undefined;

   if (data.length > 1) {
   var csv = "";
   for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
        data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
       }
      }

    if (row < data.length-1) {
      csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
    }
    else {
      csv += data[row];
     }
    }
   csvFile = csv;
  }
   return csvFile;
  }
   catch(err) {
   Logger.log(err);
   Browser.msgBox(err);
    }
  }
```