# google form is logging responses, but function in apps script isn't moving data to google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form that has logged responses, but isn't sending to linked google sheet? I have the trigger set up on correct function and the event type is *On Form Submit*. Any ideas what could be happening?

```
    // This function is triggered when a response is submitted to the Google Form.
    function onSubmit(e) {
      var responses = e.values.slice(1); // Exclude the timestamp from the submitted values
      writeToSheet(responses);
    }

    function writeToSheet(responses) {
      Logger.log('Responses received:', responses); // Add this logging statement
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('13o5d1AhslmYP3BcO1U16DxkyoCxo44rt7wgOKcq-PeE');
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

      // Write responses to respective columns in the next available row
      sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5, 1, responses.length).setValues([responses]);
    }
```

Comment: I can see that this error was caused by the "Null" Value on your e.values.  I can see that these results are already known to happen. I want to understand though your whole use case so I can provide a viable work around. I want to know why the built in Link Responses to Sheets does not work for you?

Comment: In your situation, which is your Google Apps Script the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet or Google Form? I think that the method for approaching depends on it. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43429161)

Comment: @Babanana I have a google form. The responses need to be printed to a a column range in my google sheet (column E= question 1 response , column F = question 2 response, etc) after the form is submitted.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm not sure I understand your question. I believe the bounds of data submitted to sheet would refer to the google form

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I'm not sure I understand your question. I believe the bounds of data submitted to sheet would refer to the google form`, I think that you misunderstood my comment. I have wanted to ask where your script is put in. If it's the container-bound script of Google Form and Google Spreadsheet, you open the script editor on Google Form and Google Spreadsheet, respectively. What is your situation? But, if you cannot understand my English, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Getting Response during OnFormSubmit()

Your original issue is coming from the 'Null' values. I have created a solution that will take advantage of the ItemResponses() to get the values instead. Due to limited information about your whole use case, I can only create a code that will work as what you have shared and I just made it as close as possible to your code sample this way you can interact with it with ease.

### Sample Code:

```
function onSubmit() {
      var form = FormApp.openById("changetoFormID");
      var dataToSheet = [];
      var formResponses = form.getResponses();
      var lastFormResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1]; 
      var itemResponses = lastFormResponse.getItemResponses();
        for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
            dataToSheet.push(itemResponses[j].getResponse());
} 
    writeToSheet(dataToSheet)
    }

 function writeToSheet(responses) {
      Logger.log('Responses received:', responses); // Add this logging statement
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('changeToSheetID');
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

      // Write responses to respective columns in the next available row
      sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5, 1, responses.length).setValues([responses]);
    }
```

### Reference:

[Class Item Responses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getResponse())

Comment: If you have any questions about the answer or how to integrate this into your current project. Please don't hesitate to comment your questions.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.values.slice(1);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 5, 1, responses.length).setValues([responses]);
}
```